# Need to extract date and month from mysql field in the query

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have a mysql field `emp_join_date` of type `timestamp` and its in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` . Now I need to retrieve the month and date only from that field and in the query itself . How can I able to do this ?

```
$sql = "
        SELECT
            emp_id,emp_status,emp_type,emp_join_date

        FROM
            tbl_events
        WHERE
            event_show = 'all'
        AND
            event_status != 'disabled'
        ORDER BY
            RAND()
        LIMIT 0,4   
    ";
```

Comment: Do you mean date or day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DATE(emp_join_date) for date and MONTH(emp_join_date) for month

```
`$sql = "
    SELECT
        emp_id,emp_status,emp_type,DATE(emp_join_date) as dt, MONTH(emp_join_date) as mt

    FROM
        tbl_events
    WHERE
        event_show = 'all'
    AND
        event_status != 'disabled'
    ORDER BY
        RAND()
    LIMIT 0,4   
";`
```

Comment: Thanks Saad...working now. I am using MONTHNAME() to retrieve the name of month. but it is extracting whole name. Is there any way to truncate the names like jan,july or Sept >

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function DATEFORMAT() to view just the date and month.

Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

You can aslo use the MONTH and DAYOFMONTH functions if you want the month and date in separate fields